# Send an encrypted data through kafka

Tags: encryption, aes, apache-kafka, cbc-mode

I am using AES - CBC mode to encrypt a message, then send it through kafka. how can the consumer decrypt the message while he does't have the key and initial vector.

I have confused if I have to use key exchange here, and also can the consumer send back to the producer?

Any advise

Thanks

Comment: If it is encrypted with a key and an IV, the same key and IV will be needed to decrypt it.

Comment: what would be the reason for encryption if decryption without the key would be possible?

Comment: No , I mean how I can send the key and the IV to the consumer ( how can the consumer know the key and the IV to decrypt ). Is it reasonable to send the key and the IV with the message

Comment: That's akin to sending a safe with the combination printed on the door.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/10/transparent-end-end-security-apache-kafka-part-1/